# What caused a pending status on a request to Node+express server?

Tags: node.js, express

I just want ask something noob and simple. I put my node-express web application on a droplet (I use DigitalOcean's service, Angular 1.3, Jade/Express, mongoDB, and node 6.x.x).

I have a pretty fast internet connection and it usually only takes less than a second to change page or request any AJAX call if the whole web-application already loaded before.

The problem is if I open my web application for the first time in a while. It takes really long time to load ( a minute ), further inspection with Chrome only show "pending" status, like this screenshot.
[image]

Can you help to give any advice or possible cause of this ?
I think it's in my application itself. My other web-apps don't have this problem although it is hosted at the same server.

Comment: This typically happens if you don't send back a response from your Express route handler.

Comment: You're right! I painfully trace any request from client to my router and to my server scripts. I run benchmark on my database, test any file that I think could suspend or stop node to give response. Still found nothing. 

It turns out that my nginx service (that I configured as a reverse proxy) is the problem. I just write `proxy_buffering off;` into the nginx config file, and the pending problem is no more.